# Google App Engine servlet request limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I wrote an algorithm and the algorithm will take less than one minute larger than 30 seconds to finish when the dataset is large. But I noticed one thing curious about Google App engine.

In its doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#The_Request_Timer

it says the time limit is 60 seconds for a HTTP request. When I tested my algorithm, the client side will shut down the connection with an server exception at about 30 seconds. And when I went to the console, the log showed the server side continued to do the algorithm until it finished at about 55 seconds and it will not throw an exception about this. Why the client side stops to get the server side response at 30 seconds and throw a "server side" exception while the time does not reach the time limit and there is no real "server side" exception in the backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a larger timeout in your client side ajax call.